# XML modify and writing to file beautiful soup

Tags: xml

I am using python beautiful soup to parse an XML file and write it to a different file after deletion of certain tags. But, using soup.prettify changes other XML namespaces and attribute names.

f = open('new.xml',"w");
f.write(soup.prettify(formatter="xml"));
f.close();

The changes are as given in sample below.

Original XML file.

```
<draw:control text:anchor-type="paragraph" draw:z-index="1" draw:style-name="gr1" draw:text-style-name="P2" svg:width="2.805cm" svg:height="1.853cm" svg:x="3.602cm" svg:y="0.824cm" draw:control="control2"/>
```

New XML file written from soup.prettify.

```
  <draw:control draw:control="control2" draw:style-name="gr1" draw:text-style-name="P2" draw:z-index="1" svg:height="1.853cm" svg:width="2.805cm" svg:x="3.602cm" svg:y="0.824cm" text:anchor-type="paragraph"/>
```

I tried adding utf-8 to prettify(). But, its the same problem. Is there any other method to delete a particular tag based on searching and keep all the other XML contents in the file in tact? Please suggest.

Comment: That's only changing the order of the attributes. It's not changing the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using native `xml.etree.ElementTree` module which implements a simple and efficient API for parsing and creating XML data. Its faster, better, easier and **pythonic**.

You can remove a particular element using `Element.remove()`.

A basic example is given [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file).

But if you insist on using **BeautifulSoup** (it uses `lxml`, a enhanced version of native py module) , you can

```
# beautifulstonesoup for XML parsing
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup 

xml_data = """
<draw:control text:anchor-type="paragraph" draw:z-index="1" draw:style-name="gr1" draw:text-style-name="P2" svg:width="2.805cm" svg:height="1.853cm" svg:x="3.602cm" svg:y="0.824cm" draw:control="control2"/>
"""
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml_data)
print soup.prettify()
soup.find(<your tag/element).replaceWith(<whateveryouwant>)
```

You can also use a `for` loop for editing multiple similar elements as well.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please vote it and marked as solved. Thanks.

Comment: FIY, as far as I know xml.etree doesn't have a function to prettify output.